# Update column data using SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-update

In our SQL Server database, we are trying to update the old column data in a table. In a table there is lot of data similar to **Agency Administrator**. This is data is in old format where we were taking single values in a column. Now, due to an update in data structure, we are storing the data as **["Agency Administrator"]**. The same change we want to do in the old data as **["Agency Administrator"]**. How we can update by SQL query?

Desired result should be **Agency Administrator**  --->  **["Agency Administrator"]**

[image: Image below]

Comment: This is a case where you should do some research using the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) before asking a question.

Comment: @DaleK why are you give low rating on question?

Comment: firstly you have no idea whether it was me who downvoted you or not. However I will admit I am one of the 3 who down-voted your question. If you hover your mouse over the down-vote arrow it gives you the reason "This question does not show any research effort". Which is essentially what I said in my earlier comment.

Comment: @DaleK by down voting the question it will impact on my stackoverflow profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
update mytable
set adminType = '["Agency Administrator"]'
where adminType = 'Agency Administrator'
```

This replaces all values that are equal to `'Agency Administrator'` with `'["Agency Administrator"]'` in column `adminType`.

Comment: yes, this is right but first i want to select the column and then update

Answer (score -1):

Test with below code:

```
create table test(RequestId int,AdminType varchar(100));
insert into test values(2328,'Agency Administrator')
insert into test values(2299,'Agency Clerk')
select * from test;
UPDATE test SET AdminType = CONCAT('["', AdminType,'"]')
```

Comment: you did not understand the question. it is not working. your solution will change the ["'Agency Administrator'"] to ["["Agency Administrator"]"]